R in Jupyter - Installation of package ‘rugarch’ had non-zero exit status
I had to reinstall the R kernel in Jupyter recently, and I have trouble installing the package 'rugarch' after this reinstallation. When I run install.packages('rugarch'), I get the following output:
also installing the dependencies ‘kernlab’, ‘mclust’, ‘mvtnorm’, ‘DistributionUtils’, ‘GeneralizedHyperbolic’, ‘ks’, ‘SkewHyperbolic’, ‘nloptr’, ‘RcppArmadillo’


Warning message in install.packages("rugarch"):
“installation of package ‘kernlab’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("rugarch"):
“installation of package ‘mclust’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("rugarch"):
“installation of package ‘mvtnorm’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("rugarch"):
“installation of package ‘DistributionUtils’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("rugarch"):
“installation of package ‘nloptr’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("rugarch"):
“installation of package ‘RcppArmadillo’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("rugarch"):
“installation of package ‘GeneralizedHyperbolic’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("rugarch"):
“installation of package ‘ks’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("rugarch"):
“installation of package ‘SkewHyperbolic’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("rugarch"):
“installation of package ‘rugarch’ had non-zero exit status”
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'

Making 'packages.html' ...
 done

I am working in MacOs version 13.6. I am running my installation of Jupyter through a Mamba environment. I have tried
install.packages("rugarch", type = 'binary')

but it produces

Error in install.packages("rugarch", type = "binary"): type 'binary' is not supported on this platform
Traceback:

1. install.packages("rugarch", type = "binary")
2. stop("type 'binary' is not supported on this platform")


UPDATE:
I successfully installed all the dependencies in terminal with
mamba install r-package


I still cannot install rugarch.
Installing with R produces

In file included from rugarch.c:1:
In file included from /Users/joskur/mambaforge/lib/R/include/R.h:71:
/Users/joskur/mambaforge/lib/R/include/R_ext/Complex.h:77:5: warning: anonymous
      structs are a C11 extension [-Wc11-extensions]
    struct {
    ^
1 warning generated.
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ -fopenmp -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Users/joskur/mambaforge/lib/R/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -o rugarch.dylib distributions.o filters.o fracdiff.o fracimport.o garchmodels.o garchsim.o gig.o nig.o rugarch.o -L/Users/joskur/mambaforge/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/12.3.0 -L/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-base-split_1698915189859/_build_env/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -L/Users/joskur/mambaforge/lib/R/lib -lR -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-base-split_1698915189859/_build_env/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang-8: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [/Users/joskur/mambaforge/lib/R/share/make/shlib.mk:10: rugarch.dylib] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rugarch’
* removing ‘/Users/joskur/mambaforge/lib/R/library/rugarch’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/mr/3nblyj612p39q_n6vymjqr6r0000gp/T/Rtmprg41ID/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("rugarch") :
  installation of package ‘rugarch’ had non-zero exit status 

Trying to install as
mamba install r-rugarch


produces
Could not solve for environment specs
The following package could not be installed
└─ r-rugarch   does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel).


